# Writing Ruby Libraries - hiding methods from outside the module

Tags: ruby, class, module

I'm writing a Ruby library which has a module with a bunch of classes inside it. Many of these classes need to be usable and modifiable by calling scripts, but I don't want (some of) the initializers to be visible/callable:

```
module MyLib
  class Control
    def initialize
      # They can use this
    end

    def do_stuff
      Helper.new('things')
    end
  end

  class Helper
    # Shouldn't be visible 
    def initialize(what)
      @what = what
    end

    def shout
      @what
    end
  end
end

c = MyLib::Control.new
h = c.do_stuff
p h.shout
# => "things"
# ^ All of this is desired

# v This is undesirable
p MyLib::Helper.new('!')
# => <MyLib::Helper @what='!'>
```

If it's a simple thing, then I'd also appreciate the generated RDoc not even include the `.new` method for the `Helper` class either. Any ideas?

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My original answer was completely wrong, as @Matthew pointed out.  But there are other workarounds.  For instance, you can assign an anonymous class to a class variable on `Control`, and still define methods as normal by using `class_eval`:

```
module MyLib
  class Control
    def initialize
    end

    def do_stuff
      @@helper.new('things')
    end

    @@helper = Class.new
    @@helper.class_eval do
      def initialize(what)
        @what = what
      end

      def shout
        @what
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The snippet

```
c = MyLib::Control.new
h = c.do_stuff
p h.shout
```

still writes `"things"`, but now there's no way to access `@@helper` except through the class variable.  If someone *really* wants to access it my reopening the `Control` class or using `class_eval`, there's nothing to stop them, but that's just something you have to deal with in a dynamic language.

I chose to assign the anonymous class to a class variable so that it would only be created once; but if you don't care about redefining the anonymous class many times, there's no reason it couldn't be an instance variable.

Comment: unfortunately this is broken.  It does raise a syntax error because Helper is now in Control.  However `p MyLib::Control::Helper.new('!')` now works despite the private.

Comment: @Matthew: You're right.  That was a really dumb error on my part.  I've written another workaround that isn't victim to such a dumb error but that still solves the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Ruby has [access control](http://www.rubyist.net/~slagell/ruby/accesscontrol.html).

Comment: Wouldn't defining it as private prevent me from calling  `Helper.new` from the `Control` class?